# Xamarin.Forms SystemFontOfSize missing some overloads

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

According to Xamarin.Forms [documentation](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/fonts/#FontAttributes), I should be able to set font attributes using `Font.SystemFontOfSize([size], [FontAttributes])` method. But when I create a new Blank App (Xamarin.Forms Portable) project and add the following code to App.cs in the portable project, for some reason I don't have access to all of the overloads for `Font.SystemFontOfSize(...)` and no access to `Xamarin.Forms.FontAttributes` enum.

```cs
// FontExample/App.cs
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
namespace FontExample {
    public class App {
        public static Page GetMainPage() {
            return new ContentPage {
                Content = new Label {
                    Text = "Hello, Forms !",
                    Font = Font.SystemFontOfSize(14, FontAttributes.Italic)
                },
            };
        }
    }
}
```

There seem to be only two overloads of SystemFontOfSize and the compiler gives me:

> The name 'FontAttributes' does not exist in the current context [...]

The project seem to have all the default references in place (.NET, Xamarin.Forms.Core, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml), I did not touch them.

But, if I download [a sample project](http://developer.xamarin.com/samples/WorkingWithFonts/) with exactly the same setup (calling `Font.SystemFontOfSize` from within the portable project with the same references), the project compiles fine and I seem to have access to all of the `Font.SystemFontOfSize` overloads as well as the `Xamarin.Forms.FontAttributes` enum.

Why don't I have access to all Xamarin.Forms API features when creating a new project myself? I can't find any significant difference between the newly created Blank App (Xamarin.Forms Portable) and the sample project linked above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your build is getting confused somewhere.

Try removing the **Xamarin.Forms** references via **NuGet**; close-down the project and re-open; re-add **Xamarin.Forms** via **NuGet**.  The current latest version should be like v1.2.3x.

If the above approach doesn't work, try doing a clean build (In Visual Studio, Build -> Clean Solution') and then try to rebuild.

As a final resort go into each application folder and delete the 'obj' and 'bin' directories and rebuild.

One of the above should resolve your issue.

Note - however that there is an issue with using `Font.SystemFontOfSize({fontsize}, {font-attributes-enum})`, in a previous version of **Xamarin.Forms** that would cause **this overload** to **crash** the application with an **exception**.

Unless they have now corrected this you will need to use something like  `Font.SystemFontOfSize(30).WithAttributes(FontAttributes.Bold)` instead to get around this.

Comment: Thanks Pete! Uninstalling and re-installing Xamarin.Forms solved the issue for me! They should have big screaming "BETA" label next to Xamarin.Forms. This thing seem to be far from being ready for production use.